# Fetch blob is not handling url with # character inside the filename

Tags: javascript, fetch, blob

I use this javascript code to download a binary file from the backend.

```
        // This is only a helper class for Ajax request
        new SimpleAjaxRequest().safeRequest("mainpage/downloaddocument.php",
        {
            questionnaireid: questionnaire.id
        }, true, false, (response) =>
        {
            fetch(response.data.url) // This url is like "xxxx.com/download/filename #1.xlsx"
                .then(resp => resp.blob())
                .then(blob =>
                {
                    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                    const a = document.createElement('a');
                    a.style.display = 'none';
                    a.href = url;
                    // the filename you want
                    a.download = response.data.name;
                    document.body.appendChild(a);
                    a.click();
                    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
                })
                .catch(() => alert('Document not found!'));
        });
}
```

But the link is trying to get a file named "xxxx.com/download/filename ". So it stops at the "#" character.
Is there any way to make this work or do I have to replace the whole code with something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a url, the `#` indicates the end of the part of the url sent to the server and the start of the "hash"  or "fragment" which tells the client which heading to scroll to on the page. Thus, anything after the # will be ignored by the server.

Fix it by replacing # with the url-encoded version: `%23`. Do so automatically with `encodeURIComponent`.

```
encodeURIComponent('abc#.xlsx') === 'abc%23.xlsx'.
```

You want to only encode the part after the last `/`, not the whole url.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have url encoded the filename on the backend side now and it works like a charm. I already tried that before but my problem was I used the wrong PHP command urlencode() which is replacing spaces with + signs, which is not useable for the fetch. Now I use rawurlencode().